# Is there a Riemann integrable function such that its fourier coefficients are the following:

Tags: fourier-series, riemann-integration

$a_0=0, a_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}, b_n=\frac1n$

This is a homework question. The solution says that there is no such function, because that would mean that series $\sum a_n^2$ converges, which we know to be false.

I'm not sure where that comes from as I haven't really understood the relation between the fourier series and its coefficients. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I guess that $a_m$ is the coefficient of $cos(mx)$ and $b_n$ is the coefficient of $\sin(nx)$, am I right?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is $2\pi$-periodic and Riemann-integrable over $[0,2\pi]$ then $f(x)\in L^2([0,2\pi])$, and the same applies to $f_{\text{even}}(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$. On the other hand your assumptions lead to $\left\|f_{\text{even}}(x)\right\|_2=+\infty$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio  yes.